# <Option> dentro de <Select> selecionada por padrão baseada em variavel passada pela URL

Tags: php, html, html-select, html-option, selected-option

Quero que o select de cursos tenha o valor(curso) selecionado por padrão quando o usuário acessar a pagina pelo link.

```
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">  
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.css">
        <link rel = "Stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "styles/menu.css">
        <link rel = "Stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "styles/paginas.css">
       <title>Biblioteca Solon Tavares</title>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <nav class="menu">
            <div id="logo">Biblioteca Solon Tavares</div>
                <ul>                
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="mna">Início </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#cursosc" class="mna mn1">Cursos 
                        <span class="baixo"></span></a>
                        <ul id="ulb" class="ul1">                           
                            <li><a href="paginas/ti.html" class="centra-vr">Técnico em Informática</a></li>
                            <li><a href="paginas/tr.html">Técnico em Redes de Computadores</a></li>
                            <li><a href="paginas/te.html">Técnico em Eletroeletrônica</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#tccsc" class="mna mn2">TCCS 
                        <span class="baixo"></span></a>
                        <ul id="ulq" class="ul2">
                            <li><a href="paginas/tcc/tcc.php?cr=ti" class="centra-vr">Técnico em Informática</a></li>
                            <li><a href="paginas/tcc/tcc.php?cr=tr">Técnico em Redes de Computadores</a></li>
                            <li><a href="paginas/tcc/tcc.php?cr=te">Técnico em Eletroeletrônica</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="cursosc" class="secoes">   
            <div class="crs-titulo">
                <h2>Cursos Técnicos</h2>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="cr-ti curso">
                    <ul id="ti-li">                 
                    <li><i class="fa fa-3x fa-laptop text-primary"" style="visibility: visible;"></i></li>
                    <li><h3>Informática</h3></li>
                    <li><a href="paginas/ti.html#md1">Módulo 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="paginas/ti.html#md2">Módulo 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="paginas/ti.html#md3">Módulo 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="paginas/ti.html#md4">Módulo 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> 
                <div class="cr-tr curso">
                    <ul id="tr-li">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-3x fa-wifi text-primary" style="visibility: visible;"></i></li>
                    <li><h3>Redes de Computadores</h3></li>
                    <li><a href="paginas/tr.html#md1">Módulo 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="paginas/tr.html#md2">Módulo 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="paginas/tr.html#md3">Módulo 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="paginas/tr.html#md4">Módulo 4</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </div>
                <div class="cr-te curso">
                    <ul id="te-li">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-3x fa-code-branch text-primary" style="visibility: visible;"></i></li>
                    <li><h3>Eletroeletrônica</h3></li>
                    <li><a href="paginas/te.html#md1">Módulo 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="paginas/te.html#md2">Módulo 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="paginas/te.html#md3">Módulo 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="paginas/te.html#md4">Módulo 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tccsc" class="secoes">
            <div class="crs-titulo">
                        <h2>Trabalhos de conclusão de curso</h2></li>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="tcc curso">
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-3x fa-search text-primary" style="visibility: visible;"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-file-alt text-primary" style="visibility: visible;"></i></li>
                        <li><a href="paginas/tcc/tcc.php?cr=te">Técnico em Eletroeletrônica</a></li>
                        <li><a href="paginas/tcc/tcc.php?cr=ti">Técnico em Informática</a></li>
                        <li><a href="paginas/tcc/tcc.php?cr=tr">Técnico em Redes de Computadores</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Página que recebe e que será acessada:

```
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">  
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.css">
    
        <link rel = "Stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "../../styles/menu.css">
        <link rel = "Stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "../../styles/paginas.css">      
       <title>Biblioteca Solon Tavares</title>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <nav class="menu">
            <div id="logo">Biblioteca Solon Tavares</div>
                <ul>                
                    <li><a href="../../index.html" class="mna">Início   </a></li>
                    <li class="swmn"><a href="#" class="mna mn1" >Cursos 
                        <span class="baixo"></span></a>
                        <ul id="ulb" class="ul1">                           
                            <li><a href="../ti.html" class="centra-vr">Técnico em Informática</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../tr.html">Técnico em Redes de Computadores</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../te.html">Técnico em Eletroeletrônica</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="swmn"><a href="#" class="mna mn2">TCCS 
                        <span class="baixo"></span></a>
                        <ul id="ulq" class="ul2">
                            <li><a href="tcc.php" class="centra-vr">Técnico em Informática</a></li>
                            <li><a href="tcc.php">Técnico em Redes de Computadores</a></li>
                            <li><a href="tcc.php">Técnico em Eletroeletrônica</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hdmn"><a href="#pqsbox" class="mna mn2">Pesquisa 
                        <span class="baixo"></span></a>                     
                    </li>
                    <li class="hdmn"><a href="#buscartcc" class="mna mn2">TCCS
                        <span class="baixo"></span></a>                     
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="tccsc" class="secoes">
          <div id="pqsbox">
                <div id="tttcc" class="crs-titulo"> 
                    <h2>Busca por TCC</h2>
                    <hr>
                    </div>
                <div id="buscatc" class="container">
                    <?php $pdcurso=$_GET["cr"]?>
                  <form action="tcc.php" method="POST">
                        <div class="bttbusc">  
                          <label for="buscatcc"><input type="search" id="buscatcc" name="pesquisatcc" placeholder="Ex: EcoGuaiba"></label>
                          <button id="buscar" type="submit" name="bsctcc"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-search text-primary" style="visibility: visible;"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <select class="select" name="cursosl">  
                            <option class="ng" value ="">Curso:</option>
                            <option value = "tecnicoinformatica">TI</option>
                            <option value = "tecnicoeletronica">TE</option>
                            <option value = "tecnicoredes">TR</option>
                            <option value = "todos">Todos</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="select" name="anocr"> 
                            <option class="ng" value ="">Ano:
                            <option value = "2020">2020</option>
                            <option value = "2019">2019</option>
                            <option value = "2018">2018</option>
                            <option value = "2017">2017</option>
                            <option value = "2016">2016</option>
                            <option value = "2015">2015</option>
                            <option value = "2014">2014</option>
                            <option value = "2013">2013</option>
                            <option value = "2012">2012</option>
                            <option value = "2011">2011</option>
                            <option value = "2010">2010</option>
                            <option value = "todos">Todos</option>
                        </select>  
                    </form>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Deve-se pegar a variavel pdcurso e verificar se ela corresponde a uma das 3 opcoes. Se sim selecionar essa opção quando a página for carregada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, para resolver isso você pode fazer uma função de comparação e dar um echo no atributo selected do próprio HTML, exemplo:

```
function selected($valor_variavel, $valor_fixo){
    echo $valor_variavel == $valor_fixo ? 'selected' : '';
}
```

Se eu chamar essa função no seu exemplo, seria assim:

```
function selected($valor_variavel, $valor_fixo){
    echo $valor_variavel == $valor_fixo ? 'selected' : '';
}

    $pdcurso = 'te';
    selected($pdcurso, 'ti');
?>

<option class="ng" value ="">Curso:</option>
<option  <?= selected($pdcurso, 'ti') ?> value = "tecnicoinformatica">TI</option>
<option  <?= selected($pdcurso, 'te') ?> value = "tecnicoeletronica">TE</option>
<option  <?= selected($pdcurso, 'tr') ?> value = "tecnicoredes">TR</option>
```

A opção que estaria selecionada seria TI.
Espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado.

Comment: <?php function selected($valor_variavel, $valor_fixo){
                    echo $valor_variavel == $valor_fixo ? 'selected' : ''; }          
                    if( isset( $_GET['cr'] ) ) {
                    $pdcurso=$_GET["cr"]; 
                    }else{
                    $pdcurso="";
                }
                    ?>

Comment: Show, podia marcar como resposta para ajudar outros que também possam ter a msm dúvida